# Replacement for .NET WebView on Tizen TV

Tags: .net, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

Tizen TV platform .NET for Xamarin lacks of WebView class support - due of security reasons or anything else:

- application fail to start with xamarin webview;
- tizen decline to create tizen.Net webview (cos its only aviable for wearable and mobile platforms).

So, because of impossibilyty of start browser page (webview) in tizen TV application,  interactive OAuth2 google authorization imposible.

Yes - I can open authorization link on TV platform pre-installed samsung browser, but callback from this browser to 127.0.0.1 (or localhost) unaviable due sandboxing of my app. 
Non-interactive authorization is only for short list of google services where google.photos not listed.

Here is the main question -  what I can use to implement browser engine into cross-platform xamarin project ?

Comment: might you format your question to make it more readable? it's a bit messy

Comment: I have tried to do it more readable. If something is not clear  - please ask adittional questions.  Thanx.